# Mouseover image interference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mouseevent

Using IE8, i have a mouseover event on a div that contains several images.

When moving over the div the event triggers fine, but the problem is that when the user enters and exists an image, the div mouseover triggers again.

Apperenlty IE8 sees hovering images as leaving the div. 
Does anyone know a nice method so the event triggers only once when entering the div and doesn't fire anymore while the user is wihtin the div's borders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter) and [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseleave) instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`